# Arquillian + TomEE JNDI Resource injection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, integration-testing, cdi

I'm trying to access a managed resource (jdbc) from tomee into my arquillian tests but the resource keeps coming back null. I've tried defining my jdbc connection in context.xml, arquillian.xml and tomee.xml but no dice...any help is appreciated.

arquillian.xml

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
<configuration>
    <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
    <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
    <property name="properties">
        testDatabase = new://Resource?type=DataSource
        testDatabase.JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        testDatabase.JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
        testDatabase.UserName root
        testDatabase.Password password
    </property>
</configuration>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true"  path="/">
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/test"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root"
        password="password"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
        maxActive="8"
        maxIdle="4"
        maxWait="10000"
/>
```

tomee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
<Resource id="jdbc/test" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    UserName root
    Password password
</Resource>
```

Injection point (db is always null here)

```
public abstract class Db extends Base {

@Resource(name="jdbc/test")
private DataSource db;

    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            return db.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) { log.warn("Db", e); return null; }
    }
}
```

Concrete class

```
public class TestDb extends Db {

    public TestDb(){
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        try {
            URI resPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("SQL").toURI();
            List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(resPath))
                                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                    .map(Path::toFile)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            files.stream().forEach( file -> {
                try(Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement()){
                    String s = IOUtils.toString(
                            new FileInputStream(file),
                            "UTF-8");
                     statement.execute(s);
                } catch (Exception e) { log.warn("loadData", e); }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) { log.warn("loadData", e); }
    }
}
```

Arquillian deployment

```
@Deployment
    public static WebArchive deploy(){
        File[] files = Maven.resolver().resolve("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34").withTransitivity().asFile();

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, "a.b")
                .addAsLibraries(files)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource("context.xml", "context.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource("tomee.xml", "tomee.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("web.xml", "web.xml");
}
```

Comment: not an expert on tomee. But, shouldn't the resource id in `tomee.xml` is `test`? as you're trying to match it with name `test` in your injection point.

Comment: Yeah saw that, was a typo. Either way though, whether it's `test` or `jdbc/test`, both end up returning null.